# How to change a buildConfig in OpenShift 3

Tags: kubernetes, openshift-origin

I'm working through the sample tutorial on OpenShift 3. I created the example application nodejs-mongodb-example. But in the "edit parameters" step, I put the wrong URL to my forked repository, and I get a failed build.

I thought maybe I'd be able to extract the buildConfig file (is that a template?) on the command line, but I haven't found a way to do that.

Is there a way to edit and replace this bad buildConfig without deleting all of the application objects and starting over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `oc edit` command to edit an existing object. For example, `oc edit buildconfig/myapp` to edit the BuildConfig named myapp.

Comment: Thank you! Naturally I found that ten minutes after asking the question. It worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

To add to @ncdc answer, here are the docs for oc :
https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/cli_reference/basic_cli_operations.html

and specifically for oc edit :
https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/cli_reference/basic_cli_operations.html#application-modification-cli-operations